# vue-bootstrap alert showing only once

Tags: vue.js

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/alert/

I am trying to show an alert on a button click for a second and hide it away, then show it again when button is clicked again,

```
    <b-alert :show="saved" >Default Alert</b-alert>

..
clicked() {
//1 sec delay
  this.saved = 1
}
```

I was hoping this would show the alert and reset the "saved" to 0 or something so when I click the button it would show again, I even tried to set the value to 0 after the click but no avail.

In their other examples they have done similar things with additional methods like 'countDownChanged','showAlert', I just want to know if that can be done without that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess, you need to use `true` or `false` instead of Numeric value. Adding more code would help.

Comment: tried boolean as well..same issue, that is pretty much all the code I have,

 <button v-on:click="clicked">Save</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the following code. Its working fine for me.

```
<button @click="test">lalala</button>
<b-alert :show="showvar" >Default Alert</b-alert>

data: {
    showvar:false,
    sec:1000
},
methods: {
    test: function() {
        console.log("hi")
        let self = this;
        self.showvar=true
        setTimeout(function(){ self.showvar=false; }, self.sec);
    }
}
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QoeNro

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer. but, could you please elaborate why this works ?

Comment: So it's simple I set showvar true in click and after one second the setTimeout will call and it set showvar to false